# Rails obtain id for Two steps form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a report system which uses a meta question model to create the reports. Basically i have a table with a number of questions like the following:

variables table:

`id | name | variable_type | description | breakpoint | time_frequency`

Now the system builds the report question depending on things like the time frequency of the report.

Now i have two tables in order to save the reports:

report_bodies table:

`variable_id | report_id | value`

report_heads table

`id | email | name`

With this approch i need to create the report and then use that id to save the answers to the questions of that report.

I have done an after_filter in the report_heads controller to somehow pass the next function the just created id.

`after_filter :go_to_report, :only => :create`

finally my empty go_to_report function

```
def go_to_report 
    #what to do here?
end
```

Thank you in advance.

### Update

So, i discovered that i could call the new function of the report_bodies directly from the creation of the report_head with this:

```
        format.html { redirect_to :new_report_body, notice: 'Report head was successfully created.', :parameter => @report_head.id }
```

And the the new function for report_bodies is:

```
  def new
    @report_head_id = :parameter
    @report_questions = getDailyVariables
    @report_body = ReportBody.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @report_body }
    end
  end
```

However when the in the view i'm not receiving the id of the report_head but a simple string instead

```
<!-- code from the view (_form.html.erg): -->
<%= builder.hidden_field :report_id, :value => @report_head_id %>

<!-- rendered view: -->
<input id="report_bodies_report_id" name="report_bodies[report_id]" value="parameter" type="hidden">
```

Comment: I guess you already got pretty so far, but if everything fails, check out [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked). I had a good experience using it dealing with user registration form that's pretty complex.

Comment: @garbagecollection noted, if i will give it a tray in case today is a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're receiving the simple string `"parameter"` because you're setting `@report_head_id` to a symbol `:parameter` in your `new` action.

In the `new` action, try using `@report_head_id = params[:parameter]` instead.

Comment: ok i dont know why that was not there, thanks. However putting that get things worse, rendered view: `<input id="report_bodies_report_id" name="report_bodies[report_id]" type="hidden">` has no value

Comment: I just want to be sure, but `@report_head` has been created already when you're setting `:parameter => @report_head.id` right? That's the only thing I can think of right now that would be causing `params[:parameter]` to be blank.

Comment: Yes sure, i put that code just after `@report_head.save` i did not put the complete code above as i though it was not necessary. And yes, in the index there are a lot of reports created.